# How to fix 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' error in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with a column that I would like to get some information from. I need to create a new database (I called it "df_topic") where I have the "topics" and "total" collected from the column "board_data" of the "df" database.

I have tried some code but I am getting an error that I don't know how to solve.

This is a sample of the database:

```
df = [{"username": "last",
    "board_data": "{\"boards\":[{\"postCount\":\"75\",\"topicCount\":\"5\",\"name\":\"Hardware\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":80},{\"postCount\":\"20\",\"topicCount\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Marketplace\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":31},{\"postCount\":\"26\",\"topicCount\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Atari 5200\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":27},{\"postCount\":\"9\",\"topicCount\":0,\"name\":\"Atari 8\",\"url\"\"totalCount\":9}"
    },
    {"username": "truk",
     "board_data": "{\"boards\":[{\"postCount\":\"351\",\"topicCount\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Atari 2600\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":362},{\"postCount\":\"333\",\"topicCount\":\"22\",\"name\":\"Hardware\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":355},{\"postCount\":\"194\",\"topicCount\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Marketplace\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":202}"
    }]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

This is the expected result:

```
   username   topic      total
0   last     Hardware     80
1   last     Marketplace  31
2   last     Atari 5200   27
3   last     Atari 8      9
4   truk     Atari 2600   362
5   truk     Hardware     355
6   truk     Marketplace  202
```

This is the code I am using, but there is a TypeError:

```
topics = df.set_index('username').board_data.str.extractall(r'name([^,]*)')
total = df.set_index('username').board_data.str.extractall(r'totalCount\":([^,]*)')

data = []
for username in df.username.unique():
for topic, total in zip(topics[0][username], total[0][username]):
    data.append([username, topic, total])
df_topic = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='username,topic,total'.split(','))
print(df_topic)
```

This is the error I am getting:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from trying to manipulate string objects as if they were `dict`-like. If you were using Pandas' `.loc` or `.iloc` syntax to index/slice [[docs]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) this would be clearer.

I recommend backing up and addressing the root of your problem. You should fix what I am guessing is the mangled JSON that you are trying to parse into DataFrames. This is what the offending part of your examples look like when cleaned up as valid JSON:

```
'{"boards":[{"postCount":"75","topicCount":"5","name":"Hardware","totalCount":80},{"postCount":"20","topicCount":"11","name":"Marketplace","totalCount":31},{"postCount":"26","topicCount":"1","name":"Atari 5200","totalCount":27},{"postCount":"9","topicCount":0,"name":"Atari 8","totalCount":9}'
```

You can then use `json.loads` to translate those strings into valid Python objects:

```py
from_json = [{"username": "last",
    "board_data": {'boards': [{'postCount': '75',
   'topicCount': '5',
   'name': 'Hardware',
   'totalCount': 80},
  {'postCount': '20',
   'topicCount': '11',
   'name': 'Marketplace',
   'totalCount': 31},
  {'postCount': '26',
   'topicCount': '1',
   'name': 'Atari 5200',
   'totalCount': 27},
  {'postCount': '9', 'topicCount': 0, 'name': 'Atari 8', 'totalCount': 9}]}},
{"username": "truk",
     "board_data": {'boards': [{'postCount': '351',
   'topicCount': '11',
   'name': 'Atari 2600',
   'totalCount': 362},
  {'postCount': '333',
   'topicCount': '22',
   'name': 'Hardware',
   'totalCount': 355},
  {'postCount': '194',
   'topicCount': '8',
   'name': 'Marketplace',
   'totalCount': 202}]}}]
```

Having parsed your data as above, you can completely avoid string manipulations within Pandas like this:

```py
dfs = []
for i in range(2):
    _df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(from_json[i]['board_data']['boards'])
    user_df = _df.assign(username=from_json[i]['username'])
    user_df.drop(columns=['postCount', 'topicCount'], inplace=True)
    dfs.append(user_df)

single_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0).sort_values('username').reset_index(drop=True)
```

You should end up with this DataFrame, after which you can easily clean up column names and column order to your liking:

```py
print(single_df)
```

```
          name  totalCount username
0     Hardware          80     last
1  Marketplace          31     last
2   Atari 5200          27     last
3      Atari 8           9     last
4   Atari 2600         362     truk
5     Hardware         355     truk
6  Marketplace         202     truk
```

Comment: It works with your JSON data, but how can I clean my JSON file to make it look like yours?

Comment: @pesc9, you can post that as a separate question :) For example your data has "url" keys with no associated value, but the `json` module expects `{key: value}` syntax. Just run `json.loads` on your data and work through the exceptions. BTW if my solution above works please mark as accepted.